# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Getting different values dbId from "viewer.model.search" and "viewer.getSelection()"

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm trying to isolate some elements that I search with the method `viewer.model.search` but when I use the `viewer.isolate` method I get everything to hide.

I already use the `getSelection` to isolate elements and I notice that they give me different dbId values for the same element. With `getSelection` dbId works but with the `search` doesn't

Does that anyone have this same error?

**UPDATE 3/11/2019:**
While I was trying to figure out what happened, I realized that the `search` method gives you the number minus one, for example: if you get with the `getSelection` the number 2302, the `search` gives you 2301.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be caused by those **dbId's** representing the same element at a different level in the hierarchy. When you select something in the **UI** by clicking on it, then the leaf (the lowest element in the hierarchy tree, usually a **body** or **solid**) is selected.

You can check in the **Hierarchy** **Browser** panel which exact node is being selected:
[image]

Also talking about this phenomenon, here is an article on overriding at which level an element is selected:
[Selection override](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override)

Edit: the dbId number of the parents of Body and Solid leaf entities tend to be one less than the dbId of the leaf itself as shown in this picture:
[image]

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the answer. But I already discard this option, because I looked for every group id and no one equals to the one that "search" gives me. After a while trying I watch that the "search" method gives me the number - 1.

Comment: That points exactly in the direction of what I was pointing out - see the edited reply.

Comment: This article on doing quick tests might also come handy [https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/do-simple-viewer-api-tests-quickly](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/do-simple-viewer-api-tests-quickly)

Comment: So I'm getting the first element that the search finds out in that group. Is there a way to get all elements and not the first one of the group?

Comment: I thought I might as well create a blog post on this. I hope it contains everything you need: [search returns different dbId than selection in UI](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-returns-different-dbid-selection-ui)

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't help me at all. I still need a way to search all elements with the criteria keynote=00000. I think I will do it manually for the moment.

Comment: Could you provide a non-confidential model, as small as possible, and show how exactly you are calling the search() function?