# When using search function of Autodesk Forge Viewer on elements in linked models, the returned dbId cannot do fitToView, but dbId + 1 works?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to search an element using search function in the viewer, then perform a fitToView on the element.  The function returned a dbId, but fitToView does not work on it.  After some research, and some help from this question: [Autodesk Forge Viewer - Getting different values dbId from "viewer.model.search" and "viewer.getSelection()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081846/autodesk-forge-viewer-getting-different-values-dbid-from-viewer-model-search), I added a 1 to the returned dbId and then the fitToView worked!

The element I was trying to search is in a linked model - I've uploaded a ZIP file of Revit models - the element is not in the main model.  Is this a known behaviour with linked models?  Can I safely add 1 to all the dbIds returned from a search to get to the correct element?  Or is there any way I can get the correct dbId?

I've downloaded the model.sdb and realized that the correct dbId carries an attribute called "instanceof_objid" whose value is the dbId returned from search function.  Is there any function from the Viewer API to get to this attribute?

Hope this is clear as mud...  Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATES:**
Using a simple model, I searched for an element in the linked file -

```
            thisViewer.search('testing', function(c)
            {
                thisViewer.utilities.fitToView(c);
                thisViewer.select(c);
                console.log(c);
            })
```

The returned dbId is 6388, and the fitToView actually zoom to the whole model, not zoom to that element.  The select also didn't highlight the element.  When I select the element in the viewer and do getProperties:

```
            var ids = thisViewer.getSelection();
            for (let id of ids) {
                thisViewer.getProperties(id, retrieveProps, retrievePropsError);
            }
            function retrieveProps(data) {
                console.log(data.name);
                console.log("dbId = " + data.dbId);}
```

The dbId of that element is 6389.  It is +1 of the dbId returned from the search function.

I then tried running the same code for an element in the main file (not the linked file), the dbIds returned are the same!  The select function also did highlight that element on the viewer.  Is this the normal behaviour when working with elements in linked files?

Comment: I have tested with a `Parent.rvt` with 2 linked models, used the number that appears on the name to search: `viewer.search('352732', function(e){viewer.utilities.fitToView(e)})`, worked fine. Is this happening only on this model? Usually the +1 means a child element...

Comment: Can you try to search an element in one of the linked models using another property (e.g a custom parameter?)?  When I do a getProperties on the returned dbId, the name property of the dbId is actually undefined...

Comment: would it be possible to upload that file to viewer.autodesk.com and share the link with me? if so, please send it to forge.help at autodesk.com (please add a link to this SO question, so I know what is about.

Comment: I couldn't upload a ZIP file to viewer.autodesk.com, so I've emailed the ZIP file instead.  Hope that is ok.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, works fine searching for `AutodeskForge` within a linked Revit model with Viewer v6.

[image: search/fitToView]

```
viewer.search('AutodeskForge', function(e)
{
   viewer.utilities.fitToView(e);
   viewer.select(e);
   console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: Hi Augusto, I tried it again on a simple model but got the same behaviour - I've posted updates on what I found in my question above.  Do you see the same behaviour?